# Disabling DHCP server in Windows-7

Tags: windows-7, dhcp

I am trying to set up a `DHCP` IP exclusion within the `DHCP` server which is coming with Internet Connection Sharing of `Windows 7` but I'm having a hard time doing so. Consequently I got a 3rd party `DHCP` software and this gave me the perfect liberty to do so.

Now my problem is that I want to use `ICS` features in `Windows 7` but need to disable the integrated `DHCP` server - how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't customize ICS all that much. If you only need routing and NAT services from it, consider just using [***RRAS***](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754634%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) instead. It is configurable and does not come with a bundled DHCP server.

Comment: It works on Windows 7? Rras I mean

Answer (score 0):

You can disable DHCP and DNS proxying of the ICS in the `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\ICS\EnabledDHCP` (DNS) registry setting. Set the 1 to 0 and then restart the service.